# Why does //div[@title='value'] may not work?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get this div, but for some reason it doesn't work:

[image]

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because of inconsistent quotes usage (apostrophe might be recognized as closing single quote)

Try to put title value into double quotes:

```
//div[@title="Best Aliexpress Women's Watches"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about quotes differences.

Comment: If I'd like to make it universal why it does not allow me to write like this: `//div[@title="Best Aliexpress Women's Watches"] | //div[@title='Best Aliexpress Women's Watches']`?

Comment: @F.Vosnim , as I said apostrophe recognized as closing single quote, so your expression is not valid because for parser it looks like `//div[@title='Best Aliexpress Women'` - no closing square brackets for predicate. So even if your first XPath returns element adding `| //div[@title='Best Aliexpress Women's Watches']` will make the whole expression invalid

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there anything I can do to make it valid for bouth cases: `//div[@title="Anything"]` and `//div[@title='Anything']` with XPATH?

Comment: @F.Vosnim , I'm not sure why you need that, because in XPath `"Anything" == 'Anything'`

Comment: I need that because some divs which I'd like to get have `'` in their title name, others have `"` inside.

Comment: @F.Vosnim you can try back-slash as escaping character: `"//div[@title=\"Best Aliexpress Women's Watches\"]"`